# Increasing email quota of all my application id on google app engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

We have multiple applications on google app engine account with different application id. We have limit of 100 emails/day with respect to each application id. How can we increase it using any api? Provide details how many emails we can send with that api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't programatically change the email quota. From [Quotas and limits](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mail/#quotas_and_limits):

> The quota is reset daily. If you exceed the daily quota, you will get
>   an [over quota exception](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#When_a_Resource_is_Depleted). If you need to send more mail then the
>   quota allows, you can use a third-party mail provider, such as
>   [SendGrid](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mail/sendgrid) or [Mailgun](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mail/mailgun).

It seems [Mailjet](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mail/mailjet) is also a partner 3rd party provider.