# How we can increase Email Quota of an Application which is hosted on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am hosting an App using Google App Engine on Google Cloud Platform.

This app send Email notifications when particular actions triggers.

The email quota for the same is been setup as 100 by default.

I would like to know how to extend this quota upto 500.

Looking forward for your reply.

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Increasing email quota of all my application id on google app engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47309594/increasing-email-quota-of-all-my-application-id-on-google-app-engine)

Answer (score 0):

According to official documentation:

[App Engine Quotas](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/quotas)

> Is your app exceeding the default limits? If you need a higher mail
>   quota, you can [use SendGrid to send email](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mail/sending-messages). For any other quota
>   increase, if you have [Silver, Gold, or Platinum support package,](https://cloud.google.com/support/premium/) you
>   can [contact your support representative](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/#contacting_technical_support) to request higher throughput
>   limits. Otherwise, you can submit a request for more quota in the
>   Google Cloud Console by selecting the particular quota and then click
>   Edit Quotas.